# Azure Self-hosted agent - Adding MFC and ATL support for build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am fairly new to the Azure devOps and self hosted agent. During my build process I am getting the following

fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'afxres.h'.

Our project requires MFC and ATL how do I add this to the self-hosted agent ?

[image]

[image]